# putting an array into a function and odd numbers of the array don't work

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void calculate(float *payperhour, float *hoursworked, float *wage, float *overtime,int p)
{
if (&hoursworked[p] > 40)
    overtime[p] = ((hoursworked[p] - 40) * payperhour[p] * 1.5);
    wage[p] = overtime[p] + (payperhour[p] * 40);
if (hoursworked[p] <= 40)
    overtime[p] = 0;
    wage[p] = hoursworked[p] * payperhour[p];
}



void main(void)
{
int i = 0;
char employee[5][10];
float payperhour[10];
float hoursworked[10];
float wage[10];
float overtime[10];
int p = 0;
// establish the variables needed to run the formulas for pay




for (i = 0; i <= 4; i)
{
    printf("Give me an Employees name.\n");
    scanf_s(" %[^\n]s %d", &employee[i], 10);
    if (strcmp(employee[i], "-1") == 0)
        break;
    printf("What is this Employees wage per hour?\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &payperhour[i]);
    if (payperhour[i] == -1)
        break;
    printf("How many hours did this employee work?\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &hoursworked[i]);
    if (hoursworked[i] == -1)
        break;
    i++;
}
//for loop that assigns all the variables needed to figure out pay
for (p = 0; p <= 4; p)
{
    calculate(&payperhour[p], &hoursworked[p], &wage[p], &overtime[p], p);
    p++;
}
//actualy equation that computes all the pay that everyone is receiving
for (p = 0; p < i; p)
{
    printf("Employee %s:\n", employee[p]);
    printf("Pay per hour:\n %.2f\n", payperhour[p]);
    printf("Hours Worked:\n %.2f\n", hoursworked[p]);
    printf("Gross Pay:\n %.2f\n", wage[p]);
    printf("Overtime pay:\n %.2f\n", overtime[p]);
    printf("Pay after taxes:\n %.2f\n", wage[p] * .8);
    p++;
    //finishes the application by giving the user the information that was computed
}
system("pause");
}
```

This is my code I am currently taking C programming and have been stuck on this problem. When you input a user into array spot 0 (on all arrays) it works fine. But if you input information into spot 1 or 3 it does not produce a proper wage or overtime for that information. I cannot figure out why it would work on even arrays, but not on even numbers.

the wage and overtime for [1] are always coming out as numbers in the millions but the wage and overtime for [0] is working correctly

ps i know the code is not even near perfect, but i am trying to fix this problem and cannot for the life of me figure out anything or get any information on the problem that i am having.

i have edited to include the entirety of the code as it is being asked for

Comment: Posting declaration of `payperhour[]` would help.  Perhaps it is as simple as `for (p = 0; p < 4; p)`  `<`, not `<=`.  The problem may exist in code not posted.

Comment: `&hoursworked[p]` would be the address of a particular value in that array, unless that's an array of arrays, why are you then doing `hoursworked[p]` inside the function? you delcared the param as a pointer to a float, not an array.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `calculate` - what?? You can use almost any name and there is no more self-explanatory? It is pretty clear that functions do some calculations, so use a less redundant name which describes what the function does. Helps you and others a lot to understand what you want.

Comment: What is the expected value and what values are ypu getting? Perhaps, it might help if you post the test data for both successful ones and failure ones..

Comment: Do not *state* `i` or `p` in the loop statement increment part.  place the increment there and remove it from the body of the loop.

Comment: although the visual studio will allow the return type from `main()` to be `void` that is not standard C.   There are only two valid ways to write the signature for the `main()` function (ignoring the 'environment' variations) 1) `int main( void )` 2) `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Strongly suggest you correct that problem.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability, 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  in this case 4,5,10.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names and using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: this line: `scanf_s(" %[^\n]s %d", &employee[i], 10);` 1) should not compile as `employee[i]` is the beginning of an array and in C, referencing an array results in the address of the first byte of that array.  2) allows the user to enter up to 10 characters for each `employee`, but a scanf will always append a NUL byte to the user's entry for a '%s' format specifier, so if the user enters 10 characters, the scanf will place the NUL byte into the first byte of the next employee. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  3) this format string: `%[^\n]s %d` will a) input everything upto, but not including the newline sequence, then will fail because the next char to be input is not an `s`.  4) when calling any of the `scanf` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `&payperhour[p]` as `payperhour` and then using `payperhour[p]`.

Note that `(&payperhour[p])[p]` is the same as `payperhour[p+p]` or `payperhour[p*2]`.

It looks like you want to call the function like this:

```
calculate(payperhour, hoursworked, wage, overtime, p);
```

Comment: I have to pass the function as a reference. Would this still be doing that?

Comment: @Searim your question makes no sense: 1) C doesn't let you pass functions anywhere, and 2) C doesn't have references.

Comment: @Searim: C is strict pass by value. There are no references in C!

Comment: my homework assignment literally says "use parameter passing, and pass by reference" so did my teacher write it wrong?

Comment: @Searim It says "pass by reference", not "pass the function as a reference". Yes, technically it's wrong because C doesn't have pass by reference. They probably meant to pass a pointer.

Comment: @immibis thank you for clarifying that to me so technically if i run the above mentioned code (the answer we're commenting on) then i won't be passing pointers... if i am correct

Comment: @Searim You will be, because `payperhour` acts like `&payperhour[0]` (this quirk is known as *decay*)

Comment: @immibis how will this run the code for all of my arrays though? if i don't include the [p] after the parameter input then it will just run the same one multiple times wont it? sorry if i am asking noob questions

Comment: Well the `[p]` is inside the function isn't it? And what do you mean "all of my arrays"? You have 4 arrays and you are passing pointers to all of them to the function.

Comment: @Searim: since you pass different values of `p` and `calculate` uses the `p`th elements, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing a few different things here. First, the calling loop:

```
for (p = 0; p <= 4; p)
{
    calculate(&payperhour[p], &hoursworked[p], &wage[p], &overtime[p], p);
    p++;
}
```

This steps through the individual people, and passes their details to `calculate(...)`. There is no need to pass `p` in - you've already used it to get the data from the arrays. Note that the `p++` should be moved to the final part of the `for`:

```
for (p = 0; p <= 4; p++)
{
    calculate(&payperhour[p], &hoursworked[p], &wage[p], &overtime[p]);
}
```

The problem with it skipping entries is because you are repeating the `[p]` inside `calculate(...)` after it has already been applied in the call. So `calculate(...)` needs to be completely rewritten - not the logic, but the variable references:

```
void calculate(float *payperhour, float *hoursworked, float *wage, float *overtime)
{
    if (*hoursworked > 40)
        *overtime = ((*hoursworked - 40) * *payperhour * 1.5);
    *wage = *overtime + (*payperhour * 40);
    if (*hoursworked <= 40)
        *wage = *hoursworked * *payperhour;
    *overtime = 0;
}
```

But also note that some of the passed-in variables are only used as inputs to calculations, while others are output. You should distinguish between the two: only pass the values for "input-only" variables, and the addresses into pointer variables for "input/output" variables:

```
void calculate(float payperhour, float hoursworked, float *wage, float *overtime)
{
    if (hoursworked > 40)
        *overtime = ((hoursworked - 40) * payperhour * 1.5);
    *wage = *overtime + (payperhour * 40);
    if (hoursworked <= 40)
        *wage = hoursworked * payperhour;
    *overtime = 0;
}

for (p = 0; p <= 4; p++)
{
    calculate(payperhour[p], hoursworked[p], &wage[p], &overtime[p]);
}
```

Note I have also changed your indenting - perhaps you need braces (`{` and `}`) around the statements in the `if`?

Comment: as far as the p++ going at the end of the for statement i tried that and my code didn't work, so i tried moving it to the end and it immediately worked i know that i shouldn't do that, but it worked when it didn't otherwise

Comment: also if i try to take p out of the parameters of the function it states that my function does not have enough input

Comment: @chqrlie ok so there is a logical flaw in calculate that is messing it up?

Comment: @Searim: indeed, there is, read my answer, but all these errors do not explain the symptoms you observe.  Post a complete compilable example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Searim Have you recognised that you are indexing the arrays (using square brackets `[` and `]`) in _**both**_ the call to `calculate(...)` _**and**_ inside `calculate(...)` itself? That is where you're going wrong. `calculate(...)` calculates ONE person's wage. You shouldn't be passing the WHOLE array in, and ALSO passing in which `p` to use. Re-read my answer: I changed BOTH the call to your `calculate(...)` function and the list of parameters (I removed the `, int p` at the end). If you only changed the call, then the compiler was right to complain about "not enough input"

Comment: @JohnBurger: my bad.  I'm afraid I the allusion was too subtile for a casual reader to catch, especially for a newbie, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since `calculate` reads the `p`th entries of the arrays, the base address of the arrays should be passed. It should be invoked as:

```
calculate(payperhour, hoursworked, wage, overtime, p);
```

The syntax in your loop is confusing and likely incorrect:

```
for (p = 0; p <= 4; p) {
    calculate(&payperhour[p], &hoursworked[p], &wage[p], &overtime[p], p);
    p++;
}
```

If the arrays have `4` elements, you should stop the loop with `i < 4` as the valid index values are `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`.  Also increment the index in the `for` statement, not at the end of the loop body:

```
for (p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
    calculate(payperhour, hoursworked, wage, overtime, p);
}
```

Furthermore, there is also a **major** problem in `calculate`:  Your post's indentation is bogus. With correct indentation it looks like this:

```
void calculate(float *payperhour, float *hoursworked, float *wage, float *overtime, int p) {
    if (hoursworked[p] > 40)
        overtime[p] = ((hoursworked[p] - 40) * payperhour[p] * 1.5);
    wage[p] = overtime[p] + (payperhour[p] * 40);
    if (hoursworked[p] <= 40)
        wage[p] = hoursworked[p] * payperhour[p];
    overtime[p] = 0;
}
```

which is incorrect as `overtime` is not necessarily `0` upon entering the function, and should not be forces to `0` before returning.

The function should be written this way:

```
void calculate(const float *payperhour, const float *hoursworked, float *wage, float *overtime, int p) {
    if (hoursworked[p] > 40) {
        overtime[p] = ((hoursworked[p] - 40) * payperhour[p] * 1.5);
        wage[p] = overtime[p] + (payperhour[p] * 40);
    } else {
        overtime[p] = 0;
        wage[p] = hoursworked[p] * payperhour[p];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** After re-reading your code, indexing both in the calling sequence and in the function **does** explain the observed behavior: you are only accessing even indices, as explained by immibis.  Apply the corrections explained above to correct both bugs and the program should work correctly.

Comment: thank you with help for the if else, but it still gives me the wrong output on running

Comment: @Searim: did you also fix the invocation code?  How large are your arrays? Are you sure about the `<= 4` ?

Comment: yeah my array is 5 maximum and the weird issue is that arrays [0][2] [4] work correctly but [1] and [3] dont

Comment: @Searim: post a complete verifiable compilable example, there must be another problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Searim: read my updated answer, I have the explanation for the odd skipping bug.

Comment: i had this program running without using a function and only using for loops now i have to include a function as soon as i included a function it stopped incrementing my p values so i altered it to simply state p at the end of the for loop condition then included p++ at the end of the loop and it worked. why? i have no idea.

Comment: @Searim:  I updated my answer again.  You did not apply the fixes correctly.